# Center images within div

Tags: css, html

Hello guys I'm trying to centre some images. They keep on floating to the left,I've tried text-aligning but it doesn't seem to work. THe jsfiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ydz/2/ P.S. I could probably do this when I've had some sleep, it's 5:56 in London :(

[HTML]

```
<div id="portfolio" style="height: 3020px;">

 <div id="project" class="cms design html-css " data-col="1" data-row="0" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry1" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/work_thumbnail275.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/jane-stockdale/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
                </div>
            <div id="workTags">


            </div>
      </div>
    </div>


          <div id="project" class="design illustration html-css " data-col="2" data-row="0" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry2" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/work_thumbnail2.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/street-child-world-cup-i-am-somebody/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
      </div>
            <div id="workTags">                 

            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          <div id="project" class="app database design " data-col="0" data-row="1" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry3" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/pgtips_thumb37.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/pg-tips-vs-january/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
        </div>
            <div id="workTags">


            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[css]

```
#project{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
    height:200px;
    width:309px;
    display: inline;
}

.workEntry{ 
    width:310px;
    overflow:hidden;
}



#thumbAttachment{
    float:left;
    width: 310px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inThumb{
    float:left;
}

#blackCross{
    float:left;
    width: 310px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    khtml-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;

}

#blackCross:visited{

    khtml-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
}

#blackCross:hover{
    khtml-opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=100)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:100;
}
```

Comment: You want to make all images center?

Comment: In your code there are too much unnecessary float's.So, remove float from #project & give margin:0 auto to it. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ydz/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope I understand your question well. You should use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` to make a `div` (or in a better word, a block position element) center.

For instance you should change your css code to something like:

```
#inThumb{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ydz/4/

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys. Going to bed now.